# Create Table Fallo clave foranea

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

Quiero crear 3 llaves foraneas en una tabla tal como esta:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS puo;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS puo (
    ano INT ( 4 )NOT NULL,
    empresa CHAR ( 8 )NOT NULL,
    acro_proyecto CHAR ( 10 )NOT NULL,
    partida VARCHAR ( 100 ) NOT NULL,
    proveedor VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    formadepago VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    solicitado_por CHAR (4) NOT NULL,
    aprobado_por CHAR (4) NOT NULL,
    puo VARCHAR ( 50 )NOT NULL,
    posicion VARCHAR (59) NOT NULL,
    producto_servicio VARCHAR ( 150 ) NOT NULL,
    cantidad INT NOT NULL,
    precio_unitario VARCHAR ( 10 ) NOT NULL,
    descuento_porcentaje VARCHAR ( 10 ) NOT NULL,
    iva VARCHAR ( 10 ) NOT NULL,
    precio_total VARCHAR ( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    descuento VARCHAR ( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    precio_uni_descuento VARCHAR ( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    iva_total VARCHAR ( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    total VARCHAR ( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    fecha TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(puo),
    FOREIGN KEY (empresa) REFERENCES compania(acronimo) on DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (solicitado_por) REFERENCES autorizados(acro_usuario) on DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (aprobado_por) REFERENCES usuarios(acro_usuario) on DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (acro_proyecto) REFERENCES proyectos(acro_proyecto) on DELETE CASCADE)
            Engine = INNODB
```

Y me tira error en esta línea:

```
FOREIGN KEY (solicitado_por) REFERENCES autorizados(acro_usuario) on DELETE CASCADE,
```

Para crear las claves foraneas utilizao estas tablas:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS autorizados;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS autorizados (
    acro_usuario CHAR ( 4 )NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR ( 15 )NOT NULL,
    apellidos VARCHAR ( 50 )NOT NULL,
    area_ui VARCHAR ( 30 )NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR ( 50 )NOT NULL,
    empresa CHAR ( 8 ),
    fecha TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(acro_usuario),
    FOREIGN KEY (empresa) REFERENCES compania(acronimo) on DELETE CASCADE)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS compania;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS compania (
    acronimo CHAR ( 8 ),    
    compania VARCHAR ( 50 )NOT NULL,
    fecha TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    PRIMARY KEY(acronimo))
```

Utilizo dos tablas de usuarios diferentes por que cada uno esta enfocado para realizar distintas funciones

Comment: Hola @Alberto, ¿podrías añadir el error que te está dando? para tener un poco más de información y poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: La clave foranea esta incorrectamente formada

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre es que el charset o el collation sean diferente en las dos tablas, ya que la columna a la que haces referencia es PRIMARY KEY de la otra tabla y por lo tanto tiene un INDICE creado.

Como indica la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
>   have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be
>   the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For
>   nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation
>   must be the same.

Traducción:

> Las columnas correspondientes en la clave externa y la clave
>   referenciada deben tener tipos de datos similares. El tamaño y el
>   signo de los tipos enteros debe ser el mismo. La longitud de los tipos
>   de cadenas no tiene que ser la misma. Para las columnas de cadenas no
>   binarias (carácter), el character set y el collation
>   deben ser los mismos.

Otra cosa que se me ocurre es que no estés creando las tablas en el orden correcto y no exista la tabla a la que quieras referenciar en la FOREIGN KEY

Comment: Pero fijate que ambas son CHAR 4 lo unico que cambia es el nombre pero eso da exactamente igual, y el orden no es problema ya que tengo todo creado solo me falta esta ultima tabla grande por implementar.

Comment: me refiero al  charset y collation que puedes ver en la documentación https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html